# PHP GetText without locale on server?

Tags: php, localization, gettext

I have a problem with GetText and my question actually is: Is it maybe possible to set the .mo-filepath manually?

If I type "locales -a" in a shell, I get the following list

```
C
de_DE.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

My PHP-Code likes like this:

```
$directory = './locale';
$domain = 'texts';

$locale = 'fr_FR.utf8';

bindtextdomain($domain, $directory);
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

putenv('LC_MESSAGES='.$locale);
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
```

If I change the variable $locale to "en_US" or "de_DE" and the file is available, it works perfectly. But it does not work with locales not in the list above. But there must be a way to do this without installing every language..

Maybe you know a good advice. Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible if you're using the native gettext() extension.

You could still do a dirty workaround by setting `$directory = './locale/fr_FR' and putting a folder`LC_MESSAGE/en_US' in there.

You can also use a PHP Gettext emulation, written in PHP: https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/ works even if the locale is not installed.

It will also prevent another gettext caveat: if you update the .mo file (upload a new one), the native gettext extension won't load it if it's already in its cache (where each process has its own cache). There is no way to reload it manually (except changing the dictionary name, of course...). See a question I asked some time ago: [Gettext caching annoyance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931021/gettext-caching-annoyance)

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework has an own implementation of gettext which actually directly reads from the .mo file rather than using the gettext extension.

This is probably the only way to work around missing system locales

> The Zend_Translate Gettext Adapter is not implemented using PHP's gettext extension. You can use the Gettext Adapter even if you do not have the PHP gettext extension installed. Also the Adapter is thread-safe and the PHP gettext extension is currently not thread-safe.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.adapter.html#zend.translate.adapter.gettext

Source
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/lib/Zend/Translate/Adapter/Gettext.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation of a dirty workaround that has been mentioned previously:

If my locale folder looks like:

```
locale
  fr_FR.UTF-8
  zh_CN.UTF-8
```

If I know that the systems my code will run on at least have the 'en_US.UTF-8' locale, I can make a dummy folder under each language with that name, containing the .po or .mo files:

```
locale
  fr_FR.UTF-8
    en_US.UTF-8
  zh_CN.UTF-8
    en_US.UTF-8
```

Then, I can set my locale like this

```
// Dynamically set your desired locale here 
$locale = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'

// Set locale to the same 'safe' locale every time
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');

// Call bindtextdomain with the directory containing the fake 'en_US.UTF-8' folder that is actually a different language
bindtextdomain('domain', BASE_DIR . DS . 'locale' . DS . $locale);
bind_textdomain_codeset('domain', 'UTF-8');
textdomain('domain');
```

Kind of hacky, but it works like a charm.

Wish someone would add more options to bindtextdomain so that how it handles the currently set locale can be customized

¯_(ツ)_/¯